# Location of water pressure regulator

Tags: plumbing

Is there huge benefits to having the water pressure regulator immediately after the main shutoff in terms of length of pipe?

My main shut off is deep in the recesses of my very low crawl space and I'd rather have access to the pressure regulator in my utility room.  It would still be the first connection after the shutoff but now instead of 20 inches of pipe between shutoff and regulator there would be 20 feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should make no practical difference. I'd also suggest an accessible "secondary" shutoff if your "main" is a pain to get to. When it needs to be shut off NOW, you don't want to be facing a long crawl in a nasty hole before you can get that done. Plumbing in some gauges so you can see where it's set and if it's actually doing its job is also helpful in the long run, IMHO.

Comment: I already have the secondary shutoff and has come in useful. Thanks for suggestion, will definitely consider adding a gauge.